# How to convert the PostgreSQL bytea value into Data URL value using PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, data-uri, bytea

PostgreSQL has this datatype called `bytea`. It is their version of a **blob**.

In displaying images, png/jpg/gif, the current trend nowadays is to use **Data URLs**.

My question is how to convert a bytea value into a Base64 Data URL value?

#### References

- bytea - [Binary Data Types. PostgreSQL 9.6 Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-binary.html#AEN5757)
- Data URL - [Copy image as data URI by Umar Hansa. Google Developers. May 2015](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/copy-image-as-data-uri)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may also fetch the complete image data URL from your database, e.g.:

```
SELECT 'data:image/gif;base64,' || encode(image_data, 'base64') AS image_url 
FROM ...
```

Comment: that thing worked well. Although I have to take note that instead of `encode(image_data, 'base64')`, it should be `encode("image_data", 'base64')`. Implementers should be wary though that in this solution, the resources of the database server gets being used instead of the back-end scripts'

Comment: The column name in my post is just an example. The name and if you should protect it by double quotes depends on the real database.

Comment: Yes you are right @clemens, it's just that pgsql has this own convention that you should enclose in quotes the *field names* especially if they are on an upper case

Answer (score 1):

```
$img_bin = hex2bin(substr($the_bytea, 2));
$url = 'data:image/gif;base64,' . base64_encode($img_bin);
```

Postgres bytea is a string starting with `\x` followed by hexadecimal characters.  To get the image in binary format, need to strip off the leading `\x` and convert from hexadecimal characters to binary with `hex2bin`.  Now that you have it in binary, you can `base64_encode` it.

Comment: bare naked it is.

Comment: You should use `pg_unescape_bytea` instead of `hex2bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer incase anyone stumbles here using Postgres and sqlalchemy. Thank you to the other answers for helping me get this far.

I was able to use the answer provided by clemens above and place the sql into a column_property and leveraging literal_column to insert a rawsql statement.

```
class Attachment(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "attachments"
    id = Column(UUID(), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, )

    data = Column(BYTEA(), nullable=True)
    text = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    file_name = Column(String(255), nullable=True)
    content_type = Column(String(255), nullable=True)
    model = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    model_id = Column(UUID(), nullable=False, index=True)
    meta_data = Column(JSON, nullable=True)
    deleted = Column(BOOLEAN, default=False)

    # return a data url when the attachment is an image, doesnt work in sqlite
    image_url = column_property(
        literal_column("""
            CASE
                WHEN content_type LIKE 'image%' THEN 'data:image/gif;base64,' || encode(data, 'base64')
                ELSE null
            END
            """, type_=String).label("image_url")
    )
```